# How to upload video from React Native to S3 Bucket

Tags: node.js, react-native, express, amazon-s3

I have been working for hours trying to figure out how to send a video from React Native to my Express backend to my S3 bucket. I am completely lost. Please help someone ):

Here is my code (backend and frontend on two different servers):

React Native Frontend:

```
const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Videos,
      allowsEditing: true,
      videoMaxDuration: 300, //5 minutes
      quality: 1,
      allowsMultipleSelection: false,
    });

    if (!result.canceled) {
      video.current = result.assets[0];
    }
  };

  const video = useRef(null);

  const submit = async () => {
    
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        "Content-Disposition": "form-data",
      },
    };

    //I want to send the video data to the endpoint below
    await axios.post(`${endpoint}/post`, data)
}
```

Express JS Backend:

```
app.post("/post", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    //Here, I want to convert the video I sent from the frontend into whatever format 
      necessary to upload it to my S3 bucket

    if (formData !== null) {
      //upload videoBlob to s3 to the videos folder
      const commandParams = {
        Key: `videos/${videoName}`,
        Bucket: "portal-437",
        Body: formData,
        //setting cache to 1 minute
        Metadata: {
          "Cache-Control": "max-age=60",
        },
      };
      const command = new PutObjectCommand(commandParams);

      const s3response = await s3Client.send(command);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Upload Image from React-Native-Image-Picker with axios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65838973/how-to-upload-image-from-react-native-image-picker-with-axios)